# sprintf runs locally, but breaks on shinyapps.io server

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app that reforms numbers using sprintf

This was originally part of a larger app but for troubleshooting I've cut it down to just the functionality that's causing a problem.  I've also specified which packages the function is to use, in case there are package conflicts/masks etc.

It runs locally, but when I upload it to the Shiny Apps server, it breaks.

````
```
library(base)
library(shiny)

#Function to covert between sss.ss and mm:ss.ss format
mmss_format <- function(x, ...) {
  sec <- x%%60
  min <- x%/%60
  sec <- base::sprintf("%05.2#f", sec)
  ifelse(min == 0, base::paste(sec), 
         base::paste(min, sec, sep = ":"))
}

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
    titlePanel("Test app"),


      # Show input and output
   mainPanel(textInput(inputId = "TestIn1",
                       label = "To:",
                       value = "100.45",
                       width = "100px"),              
             br(),
             textOutput(outputId = "TestOut1")
   ))

# Define server 
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$TestOut1 <- reactive({mmss_format(as.numeric(input$TestIn1))
  })
}

# Run the application 
 shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```
````

Running locally when I enter a number (100.45 is the example included above) the mmss_function returns 1:40.45 as a character string (meaning one minute, 40.45 seconds).  That is what I want.

Running on the shinyapps sever though I get 1:%05.2#f.  This is my issue.
https://gpilgrim.shinyapps.io/testapp2/

This tells me that something is going wrong with the sprintf function, where rather than interpreting "%05.2#f" per the sprintf documentation it's just printing that string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, what's your R version? This works for me on R 3.4, but not R 3.2 or 3.5.

```
# R 3.4.3
R.version.string
## [1] "R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)"
sprintf("%05.2#f", 123)
## [1] "123.00"

# R 3.2.3
R.version.string
## [1] "R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)"
sprintf("%05.2#f", 123)
## [1] "%05.2#f"

# R 3.5.0
R.version.string
## [1] "R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)"
sprintf("%05.2#f", 123)
## [1] "%05.2#f"
```

I skimmed https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/NEWS.html but didn't see anything related.

I believe the issue is with the location of the hash. Try placing it right after the `%`, like:

```
sprintf("%#05.0f", 123)
## [1] "0123."
```

Or excluding it since it adds the decimal, but you've already specified 2 decimal places with `.2f` anyway.

Comment: Your version of sprintf (removing the second hash) works, both locally and on sever and I've updated the app to show your solution as well.  Both the server and my local R are using R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02).

I'm going to accept this answer.  The version inconsistencies are still odd though.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote another function that does that same thing but uses format instead of sprintf.  It works on server, but I'm still curious why sprintf doesn't.

```
mmss_formatF <- function(x, ...) {
sec <- x%%60
min <- x%/%60
sec <- format(sec,trim = FALSE, nsmall = 2)
ifelse(min == 0, base::paste(sec),
base::paste(min, sec, sep = ":"))
}
```

The app is updated to show both outputs:
https://gpilgrim.shinyapps.io/testapp2/